# SQL Server Username Length

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, sql

I have a SQL Server 2008 running on Windows Server 2008. The database handles spatial data.

I have a select group of users that are unable to use their domain accounts when working in the database as it kicks them out whenever they try to write to the database. They are able to view the data but can not modify it.

All of these users domain logins are 10 characters or longer. ie. fmlastname@domain.com My temporary solutions is to give them a new domain account such as user@domain.com, but this in not ideal.

All the accounts for people working this job come from the same template account in active directory. People with shorter names do not experience this issue.

What could be causing this?

Comment: (Be aware that both SQL 2008 and Windows Server 2008 are out of support.) [This discussion](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/max-length-of-ad-names-for-security) indicates that AD accounts with more than 20 characters in the SAMAccountname might have trouble. But that doesn't align with your observed trouble at ten characters. (Maybe your names are two-bytes-per-character?) But if they can authenticate enough to view the data, but not read it, that points to something else going on.

Comment: Yes. For example, my username is longer than some of the people having issues with the SQL database, yet I've never had an issue (both on my admin account and my standard user account). 
I will look into the SAMAccountNames and see if I can find something there.